# Create MultiIndex pandas DataFrame from dictionary with tuple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

I'd like to efficiently create a **pandas DataFrame** from a Python **collections.Counter** dictionary .. but there's an additional requirement.

The **Counter** dictionary looks like this:

```
(a, b) : 5
(c, d) : 7
(a, d) : 2
```

Those dictionary keys are tuples where the first is to become the row, and the second the column of the dataframe.

The resulting **DataFrame** should look like this:

```
   b  d
a  5  2
c  0  7
```

For larger data I don't want to create a dataframe using the growth method `df[a][b]= 5` etc as that is incredibly inefficient as it creates a copy of the new dataframe every time such an extension is done (I'm let to believe).

Perhaps the right answer is to go via a **numpy array**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Series` with `unstack`

```
pd.Series(d).unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[708]: 
   b  d
a  5  2
c  0  7
```

Input data

```
d={('a', 'b') : 5,
('c', 'd') : 7,
('a', 'd') : 2}
```

Comment: Ok, interesting. I refrained from this as I was not sure whether it would form an index of tuples or MultiIndex. Guess this also works for recent versions. Good!

Comment: thanks everyone for helping, also for future readers this page made stack/unstack clear https://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/

Answer (score 6):

I would create a `Series` using `MultiIndex.from_tuples` and then `unstack` it.

```
keys, values = zip(*counter.items())
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keys)

pd.Series(values, index=idx).unstack(-1, fill_value=0)

   b  d
a  5  2
c  0  7
```

---

Using `DataFrame` constructor with `stack`:

```
pd.DataFrame(counter, index=[0]).stack().loc[0].T

     b    d
a  5.0  2.0
c  NaN  7.0
```